# Calculating Percent Change with Missing Dates (time series)

Tags: r, time, series

I'm attempting to calculate percent change over a period of time where there are certain days that do not have any data. The problem I am running into is that the Delt function produces NA's (I'm guessing because I have missing dates?)

The code looks something like this:

```
Date <- c("6/1/2015", "6/3/2015", "6/4/2015", "6/5/2015", "6/8/2015")
variable <- c(4,7,10,22,3)
df <- data.frame(Date, variable)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df

library(plyr)
library(quantmod)

perct.Change <- ddply(df, "Date", transform,
    Daily.Change = round(Delt(variable)*100,1))
```

and the data looks like this:

```
        Date variable Delt.1.arithmetic
1 2015-06-01        4                NA
2 2015-06-03        7                NA
3 2015-06-04       10                NA
4 2015-06-05       22                NA
5 2015-06-08        3                NA
```

Comment: Your function isn't doing what you think it should. The ddply call to group by date means you are running Delt on a single value at each time point, and Delt returns NA for each one (as Delt always returns NA for it's first point). To do this properly, I would just run df$change<-Delt(df$variable), depending on how you want to handle the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `ddply` function isn't working like you think it is - it is applying `Delt` to a dataframe at each time point and returning `NA`, as that is always the first output of `Delt` in a time series.

You probably want something like this:

```
df$change <- Delt(df$variable) / c(0, as.numeric(diff(df$Date)))
```

Where we have calculated the Delt, then divided it by the difference in days between measures.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
Date <- c("6/1/2015", "6/3/2015", "6/4/2015", "6/5/2015", "6/8/2015")
variable <- c(4,7,10,22,3)
Date <-as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
library(xts)
df <- as.xts(variable,Date)
changes <-diff(df)
```

With this I obtain:

```
> changes
            [,1]
2015-06-01    NA
2015-06-03     3
2015-06-04     3
2015-06-05    12
2015-06-08   -19
```

Those are the absolute changes per day. To convert these daily absolute changes into daily percent changes, one can shift the entries of the original time series using the `lag()` function:

```
 perc_change <- round(changes/lag(df,1)*100,2)
```

This yields:

```
> perc_change
             [,1]
2015-06-01     NA
2015-06-03  75.00
2015-06-04  42.86
2015-06-05 120.00
2015-06-08 -86.36
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way, the NA on the first occurrence is perfectly consistent with the data - we can't establish a change (in percent or in any other measure) without knowing the previous value.
In general, I believe that NA's should not represent a problem here.